# Is there any good python css inlining module for html in the wild?

Tags: python, css, email

I would like to inline arbitrary webpages using python. I've tried a couple of libraries out there but none of them works well on "real" content, such as the nytimes to take a complex example. Also, I want the external stylesheets to be inlined too. Do you have any advice? Here is my test code at the moment:

```
import requests
import codecs
from html5tidy import tidy

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/"

r = requests.get(url)
src = tidy(r.text)


from pypremailer import Premailer
p = Premailer(src)
output = p.premail()
f = open("/tmp/pypremailer.html", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()

from premailer import transform
output = transform(src)
f = open("/tmp/premailer.html", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()

import pynliner
output = pynliner.fromString(src)
f = open("/tmp/pynliner.html", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()

from inlinestyler.utils import inline_css
output = inline_css(src)
f = open("/tmp/inlinestyler.html", "w")
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Pynliner is no longer under active development and [not ready for python3](https://github.com/rennat/pynliner/issues/33). So i would advise **using [toronado](https://github.com/disqus/toronado)**.

Answer (score 0):

Pynliner is indeed likely to work best for web URLs, in particular because it's capable of handling CSS stylesheet  tags..

```
from pynliner import Pynliner
p = Pynliner()
p.from_url('http://mashable.com/2014/06/03/iwilllisten-philadelphia/')
p.run()
```

That's in theory.. in reality you'll run into some weird BeautifulSoup issues that need to be addressed..